# Function in Excel. If Value in Column A = X then Value in Column B should be Y

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a Column "Estimated Effort in Hours" and a Column "IT4YOU T-Shirt". What I want to do now is to create function: If the value in "Estimated Effort in Hours" is in Range 0 - 3  than the value in "IT4YOU T-Shirt" should be X. If the value If the value in "Estimated Effort in Hours" is in Range 3 - 10 then the value should be Y...and so on.

I tried to create this function but it does not work:

```
=WAHL(VERGLEICH([@[Estimated Effort in Hours]];{0;0,1;16,1;40,1;80,1;160,1};1);"-";"XS | <= 2 PD";"S | 3 - 5 PD";"M | 6 - 10 PD";"L | 11 - 20 PD")
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Excel-365` then try below formula.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,{0,4},{"X","Y"},"",-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Or without MS365: `=LOOKUP(A2,{0,4,11},{"X","Y","Z"})`